# making sense of HCT ACT cmos "addional supply current"

Tags: low-power, cmos, level-shifting, logic-level

I'm trying to make a low-current level shifter from low voltage (~2V) CMOS up to 5V CMOS.

I had the idea to use TTL-compatible CMOS gates in the HCT or ACT families.

But this line in the [74HCT04 datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT04.pdf) that concerns me, the "additional supply current" line.  This is not in the HC version.

[image]

Is this a static current drain?  Or only when the input is high?  Or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HCT/ACT devices have a modified input stage that is compatible with TTL levels, but is still composed of MOSFETs. Since these MOSFETs will be in their ohmic region with a TTL high, there will be a high-resistance path from V<sub>CC</sub> to GND. The "additional supply current" represents this extra drain when the TTL high (specifically V<sub>CC</sub>-2.1V in this case) is presented to the input.